# Mapping slices of an Nx tensor

Tags: elixir

If I have a function that expects an [Nx](https://hexdocs.pm/nx) tensor of a specific shape, and I have a larger tensor that includes slices of that shape, is there an efficient way to map some function over those slices?

The specific function I have in mind is [`Nx.Random.randint_split/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/nx/Nx.Random.html#randint_split/4) which expects a key of shape exactly `{2}`.  In purely functional code, you could imagine creating a list of keys and then calling `Enum.map/2`, like

```elixir
def random_values(seed, count, max) do
  key0 = Nx.Random.key(seed)
  keys = 0..(count - 1) |> Enum.map(&Nx.Random.fold_in(key0, &1))
  Enum.map(keys, &Nx.Random.randint_split(&1, 0, max))
end

random_values(0, 6, 10) |> Enum.map(&Nx.to_number/1)
# [4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 7]
# Note, for all the "random", this is deterministic
```

But note here that `keys` is a list of exactly 6 tensors of shape exactly `{2}`; it would be more efficient to create a single tensor of shape `{6, 2}`.  And in fact [`Nx.Random.fold_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/nx/Nx.Random.html#fold_in/2) supports creating this matrix

```
defn random_values(key0)
  keys = Nx.Random.fold_in(key0, Nx.iota({6)))
  # Nx.shape(keys) ==> `{6, 2}`
```

Now I'd like to be able to call `Nx.Random.randint_split/4` over each individual vector in this matrix, get some sort of collection of scalars out, and `Nx.concatenate/2` then together into a vector of results.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

I'm actually calling this to sample some larger range, so the keys won't be sequential integers like this, but it's important that they're deterministic.

```elixir
defn random_values(key0, max, opts \\ []) do
  opts = keyword!(opts, start: 0, count: 6, stride: 1)
  count = opts[:count]
  offsets = Nx.iota({count}) * opts[:stride] + opts[:start]
  keys = Nx.Random.fold_in(key0, offsets)

  # This is slow and awkward, but works
  results = Nx.broadcast(0, {count})
  {_, _, results} = while {keys, max, results}, i <- 0..(count - 1) do
    updates = Nx.Random.randint_split(keys[i], 0, max, shape: {1})
    results = Nx.put_slice(results, [i], updates)
    {keys, max, results}
  end

  results
end

import Nx, only: :sigils
test "produces the same result as above"
  assert random_values(Nx.Random.key(0), 10, count: 6) == ~V[4 0 2 2 2 7]
end
test "produces the same value at position 6"
  key = Nx.Random.key(0)
  by_twos = random_values(key, 10, count: 7, stride: 2)
  by_threes = random_values(key, 10, count: 7, stride: 3)
  assert by_twos[3] == by_threes[2]
  assert by_twos[6] == by_threes[4]
end
```

`Nx.map/3` only works on individual elements, not slices, so it's not a choice here.  An [`Nx.Defn.Kernel.while/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/nx/Nx.Defn.Kernel.html#while/4) loop is possible, but clunky, and seems to involve preallocating the result tensor and putting individual values in it, so it's not the fastest thing; this is demonstrated in the last example.  I can write an ordinary recursive function but that's even slower.

I do not have a GPU.  EXLA is not currently working on my system, so I'm using the default backend, which I know is also not the fastest.  I do have ambitions of running this under EXLA some day and I think this means minimizing the number of times data crosses in and out of `defn` functions.  I don't consider the matrices involved huge, but they're not trivial either.  For comparison, one test case creates a 131x131 matrix and runs code like this in 7-8 seconds; if I didn't want to control the keys I could call `Nx.Random.uniform_split(..., shape: {131, 131})` and get back a response effectively instantly.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of the input data and the outcome you are after? It could be smaller tensors for the MCVE. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited in a more concrete example with more concrete output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your major concern is performance and not readability, EXLA is in fact significantly faster.  On a test case cited in the question, the default ("binary") Nx backend took 7-8 seconds to process a moderately-sized matrix, but EXLA was able to do the same work in 200-300 ms.

I mentioned that EXLA was not working, and the root cause of this was a compiler optimization problem that was resolved in [EXLA 0.5.3](https://hexdocs.pm/exla/changelog.html#v0-5-3-2023-04-14).  This means that the usual steps for enabling EXLA work here:

1. In your `mix.exs` file, add a dependency

   ```elixir
   {:exla, "~> 0.5"}
   ```
2. In your `config.exs` file (or in `config/dev.exs` and `config/prod.exs`) enable the EXLA Nx backend and compiler

   ```elixir
   config :nx,
          default_backend: EXLA.Backend,
          default_defn_options: [compiler: EXLA]
   ```

The code continues to be that shown in the question: preallocate a result tensor, then use `Nx.put_slice` to fill that in within a `while` loop.  So long as this remains within a single `defn` function, data does not cross in and out of Nx space.

```elixir
defn transform(input) do
  {rows, _} = Nx.shape(input)
  results = Nx.broadcast(0, input)
  {_, results} = while {input, results}, i <- (0..rows-1) do
    input_row = input[i]
    result_row = some_transformation(input_row)
    results = Nx.put_slice(results, [i], result_row)
    {input, results}
  end
  results
end
```